"Interim condition check" in Java Stream
I am searching for "interim condition check" in the Java stream chain.
My inspiration is in Reactor (Spring Webflux) where I can write this:
public Mono<String> interimConditionCheckMono(Flux<String> input) {
    return input
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith("A"))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No string starts with 'A'")))
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 10)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No string is long enough")))
            .next();
}

And I am wondering if an analogical construct is possible in the Java stream chain, something like this:
public String interimConditionCheckStream(Collection<String> input) {
    return input.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith("A"))
            // Here I want to trow an exception if no string starts with 'A'
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 10)
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No string is long enough"));
}


This could maybe be done with the upcoming Gatherer API, but there's certainly nothing that can go there today that's even remotely nice.

@LouisWasserman I didn't know about the Gatherer API, thanks for the tip! If you have any idea how this API might be used for it, please make it an answer :) Based on the description it looks like it might have something to do with interim stream operations, but I have not found how it addresses exactly this use case.

@HonzaZidek  Note that the Gatherer interface and the Gatherers implementations are introduced in Java 22.

With a Gatherer you could perhaps count the number of elements in the integrator, and than fail in the finisher if the count is zero.

@RobSpoor that works, but why count when a boolean flag is enough…

@Holger you're right, all you need to know is whether the integrator has been called.

As said in the comments, the upcoming Gatherer API offers a potential solution:
static <T> Gatherer<T,?,T> throwWhenEmpty(
    Supplier<? extends RuntimeException> exceptionFactory) {

    final class State {
        boolean seenAny;
    }
    return Gatherer.of(
        State::new,
        (state, element, down) -> {
            state.seenAny = true;
            return down.push(element);
        },
        (a, b) -> a.seenAny? a: b,
        (state, down) -> {
            if(!state.seenAny) throw exceptionFactory.get();
        });
}

This provides a reusable gatherer for similar situations. It can be used for your example like
public String interimConditionCheckStream(Collection<String> input) {
    return input.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("A"))
        .gather(throwWhenEmpty(
            () -> new IllegalArgumentException("No string starts with A")))
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 10)
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(
            () -> new IllegalArgumentException("No string is long enough"));
}

or
public String interimConditionCheckStream(Collection<String> input) {
    return input.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("A"))
        .gather(throwWhenEmpty(
            () -> new IllegalArgumentException("No string starts with A")))
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 10)
        .gather(throwWhenEmpty(
            () -> new IllegalArgumentException("No string is long enough")))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(AssertionError::new); // should never be empty
}

This works with JDK 22, with preview features enabled.
But keep in mind that if no element passes a filter, all subsequent stages become no-ops anyway. There is no need to throw immediately at this point.
Your specific example could also be handled with earlier Java versions using
public String interimConditionCheckStream(Collection<String> input) {
    return input.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("A"))
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 10)
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
              input.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.startsWith("A"))?
              "No string is long enough":
              "No string starts with A"));
}

or even
public String interimConditionCheckStream(Collection<String> input) {
    return input.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("A") && s.length() > 10)
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(
              input.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.startsWith("A"))?
              "No string is long enough":
              "No string starts with A"));
}

This performs another search to decide for the right exception message, but this price is only paid in the exceptional case. And we normally do not optimize for the exceptional case…

Thanks, this looks interesting. I am aware that the stream is no-op after the first filter doesn't let anything go trough, however I have the same problem as you - in the final orElseThrow I don't know why the stream is empty and I really want to avoid copy&pasting the same test. I do not mind calling the test again for performance reason, but rather for general copy&paste ugliness, and a need to updating two places if something changes.

I also hope that the Gatherer API will come with some predefined Gatherers like this one :) Similarly like there are a lot of predefined Collectors

There are predefined gatherers but this one is not in there (yet). It’s hard to predict which use cases will be considered common enough by the JDK developers. It’s also worth discussing the overall design for such an operation, e.g. I can also imagine a gatherer that also implements the filtering rather than only the reporting.
